# How to join array items with custom indexes in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, join

I have an array in javascript that I need to join and send through a URL to PHP such as the following:

```
var objects = [];

objects.splice("red",0,"apple");
objects.splice("yellow",0,"banana");
objects.splice("purple",0,"grape");

var string = objects.join("+");

$("#print_div").load("fruits.php?fruits=" + string);
```

In PHP, I want to recieve the string and convert it back to an array... something like this:

```
$fruits = explode(" ", $_REQUEST['fruits']);

foreach($fruits as $key => $value){
    echo "The " . $value . " is " . $key; 
}
```

Maybe it is the join or the splice in javascript that wont make this work, or maybe the explode in php. Im not sure, but I need a solution to be able to create custom indexes to an array in javascript and then send to php and still be able to access the index and value names.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So the result of `objects.splice("red",0,"apple");` is what exactly? Arrays only work with numerical indicies. If you want string indicies, you have to use an object (maybe together with an array, to preserve order) and implement your own `splice` and `join` methods.

Comment: Be careful with passing things in URLs - they have length limits and exceeding them will silently truncate the url, causing data loss/corruption.

Comment: javascript (and most languages) do not allow custom indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is your object:

```
var fruits = {
  red: "apple",
  yellow: "banana",
  purple: "grape"
};
```

Pass it to php like so: ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/load/))

```
$("#print_div").load("fruits.php", {fruits: fruits});
```

Use it like so:

```
$fruits = $_REQUEST['fruits'];

foreach($fruits as $key => $value){
    echo "The " . $value . " is " . $key; 
}
```

Comment: json_decode is not necessary, load method will turn the data to be parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `objects.join("+")` in javascript you should use `explode("+", $_REQUEST['fruits'])` in PHP

Comment: That is actually not correct! Try sending a string with whitespaces. Whitespaces are always converted to "+", but PHP will still recognize them as whitespaces.

Comment: @Amberlamps Please explain then

Comment: @Amberlamps that is true, but if you join an array with + this will not be converted back to whitespace in php

Comment: Honestly I havent worked with PHP in a while, but as far as I can remember when you call a script like `script.php?string=This+is+a+test` and prompt the request parameters with no further treatment in the PHP script, doesnt it write "This is a test" without the "+"s?

Comment: @slash197 PHP will convert the "+" to a whitespace which is why I have `explode(" ", $_REQUEST['fruits']);`. I have ran this and its works without any issues. I think that my problem is javascript doesnt allow arrays to have string indexes, so the join ignores the custom indexes and PHP will assign numeric indexes on explode.

Comment: @Amberlamps Yes, that has been my experience too.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You'd have to url encode any + in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `push()` to add elements to an array.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [`parse_str`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) which takes a GET string and parses it into an array, keyed and everything.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `splice` wrong. Check it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).
You could pass the data to the [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method like below, it's much simple.

```
var data = {
    "red": "apple",
    "yellow": "banana",
    "purple": "grape"
};
$("#print_div").load("fruits.php", data);
```

And in php:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    echo "The " . $value . " is " . $key; 
}
```

Comment: Would this work if you have multiple args to pass with the load?

Comment: @amlane86 Yes, there is no limit.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you change nothing else in the original code, this line

```
$("#print_div").load("fruits.php?fruits=string");
```

should probably be

```
$("#print_div").load("fruits.php?fruits="+string);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a typo. Fixed now.